# Prior year returning blanks power bi

Tags: powerbi, calendar, tableau-api

Today I come to you with a question regarding a report I am working on finishing up, So I have a lot of Year over year measures in this project, and they all run okay except for 2 of them, its one called "First time complete % 2020" and "Days to first visit 2020", So what is the issue?
[image: example]
When I have a table with claim numbers / customer numbers etc it looks good, I then add the 2021 measures for Current year, this looks good too, when adding the 2020 or prior year measure it is all blank though, and if i do just claim number and remove the Current year measure so i have a table with just prior year and claim number it makes the entire table blank, even the claim number column.

I have attached photos of what I am explaining, the relationship is a 1 to many with 1 being on my calendar side, many on the fact table side.

here is the code for the prior year measure I am using `First time complete % 2020 = CALCULATE([Percentage of First Time Complete], 'Calendar(Based on PaidDT Adjusted)'[Year] = 2020)`

I have also tried the date add method with `CALCULATE([First time complete % 2020],  DATEADD('Calendar(Based on PaidDT Adjusted)'[Date], -1, YEAR))`

Hope this helps. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Think about your filter context (filters/slicers/ row level), is there any of them?
If soo, then you need to break this filter by using this kind of calculation:

```
SomeMeasure = CALCULATE( [YourBaseMeasure], FILTER( ALL('DateTable'[YEAR]), 'DateTable'[YEAR] = 2020))
```

or something more dynamic:

```
SomeMeasure = CALCULATE( [YourBaseMeasure], FILTER( ALL('DateTable'[YEAR]), 'DateTable'[YEAR] = SELECTEDVALUE('DateTable'[YEAR])-1 ))
```